# Qt:how to use sleep() with paintEvent

Tags: qt

I am creating an application in which i am using a loop within a paintevent to draw four rectangles.and i want that each rectangle must be drawn after 500ms.for that i am applying msleep().but by using this whenever i run the application,it hangs up for 2000ms and then draws all the rectangles at the same time.can anyone tell me a solution for this problem so that each rectangle is drawn after a delay.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `sleep/msleep` in `paintEvent()`. You want to process your events quickly and not spend 2 seconds in the function call. The thread cannot process any other events while it's running your event processing code.

In a simple case like this you can use a `QTimer` to receive signals four times every 500ms. In the processing slot, update a member variable to indicate how many rectangles to draw and call `update()` on the widget. Then in the widget's `paintEvent()`, check the member variable, draw your rectangles and return as soon as possible.

(For more complex animation needs, have a look at `QTimeLine`.)

Comment: can you please provide me a snapshot that how to do this for my code?

Comment: as expect drawing the four rectangles paint event is doing other things also,and i need the delay only while the rectangles are drawn.so i can not call update many times.so i dont know how to use QTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of sleep this might help

```
    QTimer *t= new QTimer();
    t->setSingleShot(true);
    t->start(60000);//this is the time to sleep in this case 60 seconds 
    QEventLoop pause;
    connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), &pause, SLOT(quit()));
    pause.exec();//keeps the program responsive
```

Refer think link [QEventLoop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html)